# The ordering of namespace reference and includes affects compilation results

Tags: c++, namespaces, include

I always think we should use namespace after includes, for example, we should use:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
```

instead of

```
using std::vector;
#include <vector>
```

but I find the second one is OK, what confuses me is that different ordering of them causes different results.See following simple example: here are two header files and one c++ file.

```
// test1.h
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
#include "test2.h"

// test2.h
vector<int> v;

// test.cpp
#include "test1.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Although test2.h doesn't include vector, but it compiles OK all above. 
What's strange is when I swap the order of using std::vector; and #include , there happens a compile error like this:

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

error C2501: 'vector' : missing storage-class or type specifiers

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

error C2874: using-declaration causes a multiple declaration of 'vector'

I do not understand the internals, does the order of namespace and includes really matter? why so this?

Comment: It should be a non-problem: don't put `using` anything in header files (unless you are doing it inside another namespace).

Comment: I think you're confusing the `using` directive with the `using` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a bad idea to dump names into the global namespace, where they might clash with user-declared names - especially in a header, where you force the pollution on all users of  that header. Having said that:

> I find the second one is OK

Only because something has already included `<vector>` or otherwise declared `std::vector`. As you can see from your later example, you get errors otherwise.

> I do not understand the internals, does the order of namespace and includes really matter?

Yes, a using-declaration can only refer to names that have already been declared.

> why so this?

Because that's how the language works. You can't usually use a name that hasn't been declared.

Answer (score 1):

```
// test2.h
vector<int> v;
```

Header files should be self-sufficient. Writing test2.h like this requires that the user both `#include <vector>` and add a `using` declaration so that `vector` can be written without qualifying its name. That means the header isn't self-sufficient, because you can't simply `#include` it without doing a couple of other things first.

You also should not be defining variables in a header file. In a header file you should only be declaring `extern` variables.

```
#ifndef TEST2_H
#define TEST2_H

#include <vector>

extern std::vector<int> v;

#endif
```

Here I've also added #ifndef/#define guards so the header file can be included multiple times without error. I've also used the fully qualified `std::vector` with no `using`: it's legal, but bad practice, to put `using` declarations in header files.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
using std::vector;
#include <vector>
```

is **not** OK, *unless* `<vector>` has already been included by that file.

The important thing here is that `#include` does **textual** substituion. It simply works as if it pasted the contents of the included file over the `#include` directive. Header files are not compiled by themselves, they only form textual parts of the source file being compiled.

So your example works because by the time `test2.h` is included, the source file being compiled (`test.cpp`) already contains `#include <vector>` and `using std::vector;` from `test1.h`. And that's also why it breaks when you swap - `test2.h` gets included before the `using` declaration, so unqualified `vector` does not exist at the point it's used.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor directive `#include` is a text replacement operation. It will read the included file and replace the `#include` by its contents. If you think in terms of what the operation is doing the answer should be clear.

After preprocessing `main.cpp` becomes:

```
// start test1.h
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
// start test2.h
vector<int> v;
// end test2.h
// end test1.h

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If you change the order of the `using` directive with respect to the inclusion of the header you will get (removing comments):

```
#include <vector>
vector<int> v;
using std::vector;
//...
```

At the point of definition of `v`, the using declaration has not been seen, and the compiler does not know what `vector` means and thus the error message.

Now back to the original assumption:

```
using std::vector;
#include <vector>
```

> but I find the second one is OK

No, it is not ok. Depending on what other includes you have before hand, it might compile, but you cannot provide a using declaration before the compiler has seen the element being declared. If the two lines above compile, it means that somewhere before the first line, the expansion of the includes already brought a declaration of `std::vector` into this translation unit. Try to compile that by itself in a single .cpp and you will see a couple of errors.